# Ruby sleep(0.05) each character, on all outputs

Tags: ruby, terminal, output, sleep

Is it possible to achieve the same effect as this:

```
"Hello World".each_char do |c| 
  print c; 
  sleep(0.05) 
end
```

on the terminal output? I think there must be an easier/cleaner way to do this than to add the code above to the end of every string and then adding new lines after each string.

Answer (score 1):

Define it as a method:

```
def slow_print(string)
  string.each_char { |c| print c; sleep(0.05) }
end
```

Then call it:

```
 slow_print("Hello World")
```

Comment: I understand, but do you know if there is a way to tell Ruby once that all the strings should be printed like this? I've tried redefining the class String

Comment: @Oscar What method are you using to print a string right now, `puts`?

Comment: @Oleander yes thats the one. is it maybe I need to redefine the puts method within the String class?

Comment: @Oscar `puts` is defined on the `Kernel` class. [See this link](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-puts).